# moveToElement mouse hovering function in Selenium WebDriver using Java not stable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 3.0.1 for running automation tests using TestNG.
In one test I'm trying to hover on an action menu and then click an option in that menu:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(getWebDriver());
builder.moveToElement(actionButton).build().perform();
```

But the test is not stable. I can see the menu opens but immediately closing, so the test fails because it's not finding the option any more.
I'm receiving this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must provide a location for a move action.
at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveMouseAction.<init>(MoveMouseAction.java:30)
at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.moveToElement(Actions.java:251)
```

How can I check if the menu is open? the perform() method is returning void.
I notice if I put call the moveToElement twice, than the test is being more stable. Is there any elegant option of doing so?

```
Actions builder = new Actions(getWebDriver());
builder.moveToElement(actionButton).build().perform();
builder.moveToElement(actionButton).build().perform();
```

This how the menu looks like when we hover over it:
[image: hover over menu]

I find this issue:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/issue-with-losing-focus-of-hover-command-when-the-mouse-is-outside-of-the-acti
which explains best my problem. unfortunately, still with no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not necessary for you to open the menu, please try clicking the option using JavascriptExecutor. JavascriptExecutor can click a hidden element as well, all that is necessary for the click to be triggered using JavascriptExecutor is that the element is present on the DOM.

Snippet (Java):

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("hiddenOptionFromMenu")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the menu to appear after the hover with a `FluentWait`, like so:

```
FluentWait<> wait = new FluentWait<>(getWebDriver())
            .withTimeout(driverTimeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(ElementNotVisibleException.class)

wait.until(x -> { return driver.findElement(menuElementBy); } );
```

If the mouse hover succeeded - the menu starts appearing - there's no reason you need to call it twice.

Comment: The problem here is that the menu does opens, but closes immediately before Selenium can locate the sub-menu button. I think FluentWait won't help here because the menu is already closes, so it will just wait for nothing. please correct me if I'm wrong.
what I'm looking for is a way to freeze the drop-down menu after it's opens, but without clicking it.

Comment: It's hard to say if your wrong without seeing the hole scenario and the website itself... So I would encourage you to try the wait first.

Comment: Is it not working with JavascriptExecutor as well?

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('element_selector').hover();");

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a timing issue.

If the menu has a transition effect, then add a delay of the duration of the effect:

```
new Actions(driver)
  .moveToElement(menu)
  .pause(100) // duration of the transition effect in ms
  .perform();

submenu.click();
```

You could also wait for the targeted element to become visible and steady (same position returned twice in a row).